# Is there a way on ojAlgo to normalize a Matrix?

Tags: normalization, sklearn-pandas, ojalgo

I am interested to know if there is a way to find a normalized form for a MatrixStore using the ojAlgo matrix library.

Perhaps a routine or a task that once performed on a MatrixStore will cause each of the rows to have a mean of 0 and a standard deviation of 1.

If one is familiar with sklearn, what I'm looking for is some function on ojAlgo that functions similarly like the preprocessing module on sklearn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not directly. You have to write some loops and calculations yourself. Here's one possible way to do it:

```
PrimitiveDenseStore matrix = ...;

SampleSet sampleSet = SampleSet.make();
for (int j = 0; j < matrix.countColumns(); j++) {
    sampleSet.swap(matrix.sliceColumn(j));
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.countRows(); i++) {
        matrix.set(i, j, sampleSet.getStandardScore(i));
    }
}
```

With ojAlgo I strongly recommend organising data in columns.

I didn't actually test that code. Possibly there could be a problem to update the matrix in-place like this.

...

With v47.1.1 (just released) it is now possible to do it this way:

```java
matrix.modifyAny(DataPreprocessors.STANDARD_SCORE);
```

Comment: I notice some of the interface comes with looprow or loopcolumn methods that allows one to attach callbacks. In your opinion which is the recommended way to loop through a matrix when speed is a factor ?

Comment: I doubt it makes any difference in a case like this. If you're looking for that last bit of performance then go low-level, and that typically means you write the code/loops yourself. What does matter is how you organise your data. In the example above sliceRow() would be much slower than sliceColumn() when the matrices get a bit larger.

Comment: thanks for your feedback ! I truly appreciate the work you put into ojAlgo.